# auto-correct can not be applied if style is "Text Body"

Tags: libreoffice-writer

When I use Tools - AutoCorrect - Apply for the first time, it works as expected. But when I use the same option again, it does not change the text. This is because the style is changed from "default" to "text body" that does not support applying autocorrect. Is this a bug?

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Start writer
2. Type adn and check it has become And
3. Undo (ctrl + z) make sure it has changed back to adn
4. Tools - auto-correct - apply. Make sure it has changed to 'and'
5. type adn again after space. Undo to change it back from 'and' to 'adn'. Make sure it is now "and adn"
6. Tools - Auto-correct - apply

Actual Results:

> Text remains the same "and adn" after step 6

Expected Results:

> It should change to "and and"

Comment: Yes. This is a bug already reported. https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=128192

Answer (score 0):

In my case "Apply" does not work, only "While typing" works
The only way to correct is to place the text cursor after the last index of the word and make space.
When I correct a word and then do undo, the text cursor stays after the last index + space and in this way I have the possibility to continue writing without correcting the word. Well, there will be times when I don't want to correct the word. I don't know if a similar mode is used for "Apply"